# Java program to ping thousands of urls

Tags: java, httpclient

I would like to write a program to ping at least 10000 urls. I wrote a small program and found that it’s not as fast as I expected.

Pinging of 100 urls took 3-4 minutes.

Does someone have any suggestions to do it in a better way.

```
private static Map<String, String> findUnreachableUrls(Set<String> urls) {
        Map<String, String> badUrls = new TreeMap<>();
        for (String url : urls) {
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                connection.connect();
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode != 200 && responseCode != 302) {
                    badUrls.put(url, Integer.toString(responseCode));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                badUrls.put(url, e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        return badUrls;
    }
```

Comment: That is not pinging. Your code established a http connection that uses tcp, which in turn involves the tcp handshake. Then the request is given to the web server running on that server. That is essentially the same logic as opening a website in your browser, which is rarely superfast. You will have to accept that checking a single url takes some time.

Comment: Try making the checking concurrent

Comment: 1, put there connect- and read timeout. 2, make a map out of the urls by their server host+port and use keep alive connections, 3, use multiple threads (with a threadpool executor or with streaming api's parallel streams), and the the urls to the same host should goes to the same thread. I would do this in this way.

Comment: @f1sh is there way we can do pinging ( assume I do not know IP and port no)?

Comment: @m4gic added connect- and read timeout  and it made a huge improvement.

Comment: @m4gic I have one more doubt.  if I split the urls set and passed each set to different thread then how should I combine the result? Share concurrentMap between the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote, I would do about in this way (not tested). Maybe if there is only a few hosts, and a lots of urls, the grouped URLs should be splitted further.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Optional;
 import java.util.function.Function;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 import java.util.stream.Stream;

 public class TestURLs implements Function<String, Optional<TestURLs.Tuple>> {

public static final int TIMEOUT = 3000;

public class Tuple {
    final String url;
    final String error;

    public Tuple(String url, String error) {
        this.url = url;
        this.error = error;
    }
}

public static enum HostNamePortExtractor implements Function<String, String>{

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public String apply(String url) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            return u.getHost() + u.getPort();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Optional<Tuple> apply(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        connection.connect();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        // are you sure? I think you would have liked to write here "and" not or
        //if (responseCode != 200 || responseCode != 302) {
        if (responseCode != 200 && responseCode != 302) {
            return Optional.of(new Tuple(url, Integer.toString(responseCode)));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Optional.of(new Tuple(url, e.getMessage()));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

public Map<String, String> process() {
        List<String> URLs = new ArrayList<>(); // add urls here
        // group by hostname+port
        Map<String, List<String>> groupedUrls = URLs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HostNamePortExtractor.INSTANCE));
        Stream<Tuple> errors = groupedUrls.keySet().parallelStream()
                // I am not fully sure, but hoping that the stream() will go to the same thread
                .flatMap(host -> groupedUrls.get(host).stream())
                // go to the server
                .map(this::apply)
                // if there was no error, filter out the optional.empties
                .filter(o -> o.isPresent())
                // get the Tuple with url and the error
                .map(o -> o.get()); 
                // make a map
        return errors.collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.url, t -> t.error));
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestURLs testUrls = new TestURLs();
    testUrls.process().entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " error: " + e.getValue());
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it's an "and", I caught that while testing. forgot to update in question

Comment: I have not updated it, but maybe it would worth to mention that you should accept the 2xx response codes as "OK" responses.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just concentrating on the other aspects of the program

Answer (score 2):

You should use parallel threads like 5 threads doing same process for 20 URLs and finally aggregating the results. That would make the results faster. The simplest solution would be to use the Java 8 Streams to process the URLs parallely. Below is a sample program for the same:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> urlSet = new HashSet<>();
        //Populate your set with the Strings
        findUnreachableUrls(urlSet);
    }
    private static Map<String, String> findUnreachableUrls(Set<String> urls) {
        Map<String, String> badUrls = new TreeMap<>();
        urls.parallelStream().forEach(
                url->{
                    badUrls.put(url,checkUrl(url));
                }
        );
        return badUrls;
    }

    private static String checkUrl(String url)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        String returnCode="";
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200 || responseCode != 302) {
                returnCode=responseCode+"";
            }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            returnCode=e.getMessage();
        }
        return returnCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: That won't "improve the results", but that will only allow you to get them faster.

Comment: @avinash  I think Using foreach here is not a good idea because all thread will compete for the same map. Should use collect. I  do not know yet how to do that exactly

Comment: @avinash I understood, how to write it. I will update as soon as I test it.

Comment: sure @nantitv. Also, let me know how much time the different programs took.

Comment: For 100 url it took 80 seconds for the parallelStream/sequential stream version. But 100 is too small to test parallelStream vs Sequential Stream. I am going ahed with parallelStream hoping that it will make a difference for 10,000 requests

Comment: Thank you for the update @nantitv . Please accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is the way I implemented.

```
 private static Map<String, String> findUnreachableUrls1(Set<String> urls) {

            Predicate<String> unPingableUrlPred = x -> !(x.equals("200") || x.equals("302"));
            Map<String, String> badUrls = urls.parallelStream().map(url -> pingUrl(url))
                    .filter(x -> unPingableUrlPred.test(x.t)).collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(x -> x.s, x -> x.t));
                return badUrls;
        }

        static Pair<String, String> pingUrl(String url) {
            Pair<String, String> urlResponse = new Pair<>();
            urlResponse.setKey(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                connection.connect();
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                urlResponse.setValue(Integer.toString(responseCode));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                urlResponse.setValue(e.getMessage());
            }
            return urlResponse;
        }
```